# First order logic semantic resolution

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

We are in first order logic and I have 2 formulas and a logical consequence:

$$u(s),\forall x(u(x) \rightarrow m(x)) \models m(s)$$

and I want to prove it using semantic resolution. (it's a didactical exercise).

I have two questions:

1. Do I have to define a domain before proceeding to the semantic resolution?
2. In this case, is it possible to enumerate every possible case? When is it not possible?

Comment: Never heard of 'proof by semantic resolution' .... do you have an example?

Comment: I found this slide, but i didnt understand the general producedure. Can you reply me considering my first post ? https://ibb.co/cxKZ2n